# Best resource for raspi-config equivalents in config.txt

Tags: serial, raspi-config, config.txt

I am trying to figure out how to edit my /boot/config.txt with the same functionality implicit in raspi-config.  For example, I'd like to know how to enable/disable for "P6 Serial" in this screenshot from a Pi Zero W:

[image]

I have reviewed the "README" in /boot/overlays, although it is hard to discern exactly which settings correlate to which commands in raspi-config.

Comment: Be aware that a few commands (serial being one) will also change the command line file /boot/cmdline.txt Also, some options (USB device / networking) are not available in raspi-config and have to be manually entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the script itself on your system. raspi-config is a bash script and you can look at it with any text / code editor. The file is at `/usr/bin/raspi-config`

Or have a look at it in the Raspberry Pu github repo: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config

Answer (score 1):

The Foundation documentation is @ [config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/)

This is quite comprehensive, and more up-to-date than some references.

Most of the documentation in `/boot/overlays` has no counterpart in *raspi-config* and is more related to *Device Tree* options.

As Androo has mentioned some *raspi-config* options e.g. serial console are changed in `cmdline.txt`.

If you are interested in serial [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 or later](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) may help, although *raspi-config* is the easiest.
The Foundation serial documentation is @  [UART](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md)

PS If you really want to know what *raspi-config* does it is a "simple" bash script - if somewhat long and convoluted. There is no need to go to github - just look at `/usr/bin/raspi-config`